# Neo4j upgrade to 4.0.6: Failed to link org/neo4j/cypher/internal/v4_0/parser/Expressions when deploying in an application server (Wildfly 18)

Tags: java, neo4j, wildfly

I have updated the old neo4j 3.5.7 version to the 4.0.6 and I have followed the migration guide. The unit tests are running, but as soon as I try to deploy the neo4j as embedded database on an application server, ar runtime I get the following expection:

```
at org.glassfish.javax.enterprise.concurrent//org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThread.run(ManagedThreadFactoryImpl.java:250)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/neo4j/cypher/internal/evaluator/SimpleInternalExpressionEvaluator$ExpressionParser$ (Module "my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/neo4j/cypher/internal/v4_0/parser/Expressions (Module "my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/neo4j/cypher/internal/v4_0/parser/Patterns (Module "my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/neo4j/cypher/internal/v4_0/parser/Literals (Module "my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/neo4j/cypher/internal/v4_0/parser/Strings (Module "my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/neo4j/cypher/internal/v4_0/parser/Base (Module "my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" from Service Module Loader): org/parboiled/scala/Parser
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.cypher.internal.evaluator.SimpleInternalExpressionEvaluator.$anonfun$evaluate$1(SimpleInternalExpressionEvaluator.scala:43)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.cypher.internal.evaluator.SimpleInternalExpressionEvaluator.errorContext(SimpleInternalExpressionEvaluator.scala:56)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.cypher.internal.evaluator.SimpleInternalExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SimpleInternalExpressionEvaluator.scala:42)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.cypher.internal.evaluator.SimpleExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SimpleExpressionEvaluator.java:44)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.procedure.impl.MapConverter.apply(MapConverter.java:46)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.procedure.impl.MapConverter.apply(MapConverter.java:31)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.procedure.impl.TypeCheckers$DefaultValueConverter.defaultValue(TypeCheckers.java:321)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.procedure.impl.MethodSignatureCompiler.signatureFor(MethodSignatureCompiler.java:84)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ProcedureCompiler.java:252)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureCompiler.compileProcedure(ProcedureCompiler.java:226)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry.registerProcedure(GlobalProceduresRegistry.java:176)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry.registerProcedure(GlobalProceduresRegistry.java:164)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry.registerProcedure(GlobalProceduresRegistry.java:153)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.module.edition.AbstractEditionModule.registerProcedures(AbstractEditionModule.java:95)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.lambda$setupProcedures$5(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:278)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.module.edition.CommunityEditionModule.tryResolveOrCreate(CommunityEditionModule.java:258)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.setupProcedures(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:225)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:131)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.dbms.api.DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder.newDatabaseManagementService(DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder.java:85)
    at my-application-ear-4.6.0-SNAPSHOT.ear//org.neo4j.dbms.api.DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder.build(DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder.java:78)
```

This is the list of maven dependencies I have now in the jar to let neo4j work with unit tests:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-expression-evaluator</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-parser-4.0</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-bolt</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-security</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- CVE-2008-0660 as we're running community, we don't need this -->
                <groupId>org.neo4j.licensing-proxy</groupId>
                <artifactId>zstd-proxy</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.community</groupId>
        <artifactId>it-test-support</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.parboiled</groupId>
        <artifactId>parboiled-scala_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>${parboiled-for-neo4j.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Strangely enough, with the version 3.5 it was enough this list of dependencies and it worked without issues in wildfly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-bolt</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-security</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <!-- CVE-2008-0660 as we're running community, we don't need this -->
            <groupId>org.neo4j.licensing-proxy</groupId>
            <artifactId>zstd-proxy</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.community</groupId>
    <artifactId>it-test-support</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Had someone maybe the same issue and can give me a hint? Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency and try :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You mean I should use an older version? I'm using 4.0.6, is there a reason why I should downgrade?

Comment: No. This dependency is to support Neo4j cypher query language. It's latest version is 4.1.0. You can use that as well. And yes! It won't downgrade your neo4j version.